# Problem Installing Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, stall

I am attempting to install Ubuntu on my machine since windows is messed up.

The screen i see is:

```
Preparing to install Ubuntu

For best results, pleaase ensure that this computer: 

(green check) has at least 4.6 GB available drive space    
(green check) is plugged into a power source
(green check) is connected to the Internet   

(checked) Download updates while installing

Ubuntu uses third part software...

(checked) Install this third-part software

Fluendo MP3 plugin...
```

When I hit forward I get this message:

```
The installer has detected that the following disks have mounted partitions:

/dev/sda/

Do you want the installer to try and unmount the partitions on these disks 
before continuing? If you leave them mounted, you will not be able to create, 
delete, or resize partitions on these disks, but you may be able to install 
to existing partitions there.
```

I choose yes as I do not want to mess with any windows partitions.

Then it sits and does not move. I see the "wait" icon and it twirls but does nothing else. I can choose quit but that is all I can do.

Any advice as what is going on?  Is this a hard drive issue?

Comment: did you make partitions (using windows disk management) prior to running the ubuntu installer?

Comment: No, the computer is in its "factory state" in regards to any partitions. From what I understand there is a recovery partition and a windows partition on the drive then the rest of the drive. If you want to call that a partition I do not know.

Comment: Where are you installing Ubuntu from? A CD or files on a disk (usb or hard disk)? Maybe it's the `/dev/sda` it's been trying to umount?

Comment: I have used Unetbootin to boot from a USB and I am trying to install that way. I wonder if it is the hard drive and unmounting. Not sure that is why I asked here if others have had this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and use Ubuntu's Alternate Installer. I've seen similar issues like that and the alternate installer worked for me.

http://mirror.uoregon.edu/ubuntu-releases/11.04/

http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent

http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-alternate-i386.iso.torrent

Comment: My issue is hard drive related but I assume this would work in most cases.